# Mongo bulk match and update many query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have two collections, one c1 with fields like `{'State': 'NY', 'Race': 'blk'}` and another c2 with mapping documents, e.g., `{'raw': 'blk', 'mapped_race': 'black'}`. There are many documents in c2 that may map to the same `'mapped_race'` (e.g., `'blk' --> 'black'`, `'african-american' --> 'black'`, etc.).

I am using c2 to map c1, e.g., `{'State': 'NY', 'Race': 'blk'} --> {'State': 'NY', 'Race': 'blk', 'Race_Standardized': 'black'}`.

I need to select a subset of c1 (using find or match), where certain criteria are met. For example, find all documents in c1 where `'State'=='NY'` and where `'Race_Standardized'` does not  (yet) exist.

How do I go about this bulk find/match and then update many operation? I'm using PyMongo.

Answer (score 0):

Update: resolved as below:

```
query = {
    'State': 'NY',
    'Race': {"$exists": True}, 
    'Race_Standardized': {"$exists": False}
}

updates = []

for doc in c2.find({'field':'Race'}):
    q = query.copy()
    q.update({'Race': doc.get('raw')})
    updates.append(UpdateMany(q, {'$set': {f'Race_Standardized': doc.get(f'mapped_race')}}))

result = c1.bulk_write(updates)
```